# Querying where condition on as 'something' in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query

```
SELECT to_char((CASE
            WHEN a.GATE_REL_DATE is not null THEN a.GATE_REL_DATE
            WHEN a.GATE_REL_DATE is null THEN (add_months(a.ORDER_DATE, 'YYYYMM') + 3)
            ELSE a.GATE_REL_DATE end), 'YYYYMM')  AS assumed_arrival_month,
       a.dealer,
       to_char(a.DLR_DELIVERY_DATE, 'YYYYMM') AS DLR_DELIVERY_DATE,
       to_char(a.ORDER_DATE, 'YYYYMM')        AS ORDER_DATE
from seereur.seer_arcentity a,
     seereur.seer_dropdowns b
where a.market_code IN ('UB') 
  and a.MODEL IN ('00O')
  and a.DLR_DELIVERY_DATE is null
  and a.pest = b.code
  and dropdown = 'PEST'
  and b.market_code IN ('UB')
```

This is my result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ik9z.png)

Now I want to get the assumed_arrival_month between certain month like last 5 month only(currently it is giving all months) but not able to put and condition after where condition because **assumed_arrival_month**   is in the selected area. How to achieve it?

Comment: I didn't read past the first lines of code (so: I didn't even get to read your question). In the CASE expression right at the top, you have one WHEN clause for when the date is not null, another WHEN clause when the same date is null, and then you also have ELSE. What is ELSE for? The date either is not null or it is null; one of the two WHEN clauses will always be true, so you will never reach the ELSE branch. Please explain what's going on with that.

Comment: OK - now I saw the question. It's a common question. You can't use names created in the SELECT clause in the WHERE clause of the same query. You have two options: one is to make this into a subquery, and select "from it" WHERE .... (and use the name here, in the outer query); or, repeat the same long expression from SELECT in the WHERE clause. The second option does not create more work for the query (the expression is computed just once and used twice, both for WHERE and for SELECT), but the code is uglier. The first option (which is better) (........continued below)

Comment: The first option (which is better) doesn't create extra work either, because the optimizer will rewrite the query, eliminating the extra layer - essentially the optimizer will rewrite the query "according to the second option I gave you" anyway. You don't need to see the "ugly code", even though under the covers that is exactly what the optimizer will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your existing query into a subquery and select just the values you want from that set. In the example below, I am using Nov 1st as the example date, but you can change that. Also, I adjusted the logic you were using to determine `assumed_arrival_month` since a `CASE` statement was not needed and the one you provided was invalid anyway.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR (assumed_arrival_month, 'YYYYMM')     AS assumed_arrival_month,
       dealer,
       TO_CHAR (dlr_deliver_date, 'YYYYMM')          AS dlr_deliver_date,
       TO_CHAR (order_date, 'YYYYMM')                AS order_date
  FROM (SELECT NVL (a.GATE_REL_DATE, ADD_MONTHS (a.ORDER_DATE, 3))     AS assumed_arrival_month,
               a.dealer,
               a.DLR_DELIVERY_DATE,
               a.ORDER_DATE
          FROM seereur.seer_arcentity a, seereur.seer_dropdowns b
         WHERE     a.market_code IN ('UB')
               AND a.MODEL IN ('00O')
               AND a.DLR_DELIVERY_DATE IS NULL
               AND a.pest = b.code
               AND dropdown = 'PEST'
               AND b.market_code IN ('UB'))
 WHERE assumed_arrival_month BETWEEN DATE '2020-11-01'
                                 AND ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (DATE '2020-11-01'), -5);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question is to take only last 5 months please try this code:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (assumed_arrival_month, 'YYYYMM')     AS assumed_arrival_month,
       dealer,
       TO_CHAR (dlr_deliver_date, 'YYYYMM')          AS dlr_deliver_date,
       TO_CHAR (order_date, 'YYYYMM')                AS order_date
  FROM (SELECT NVL (a.GATE_REL_DATE, ADD_MONTHS (a.ORDER_DATE, 3))     AS assumed_arrival_month,
               a.dealer,
               a.DLR_DELIVERY_DATE,
               a.ORDER_DATE
          FROM seereur.seer_arcentity a, seereur.seer_dropdowns b
         WHERE     a.market_code IN ('UB')
               AND a.MODEL IN ('00O')
               AND a.DLR_DELIVERY_DATE IS NULL
               AND a.pest = b.code
               AND dropdown = 'PEST'
               AND b.market_code = a.market_code)
 WHERE trunc(assumed_arrival_month, 'mm') >= 
                                 ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(assumed_arrival_month, 'mm'), -5);
```

Thanks.